# Get latest 10 posts from wordpress blog using Spring MVC or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wordpress, spring

I want to be able to retrieve the top 10 latest posts from a wordpress blog located at a link that looks something like this: https://thisismyblog.wordpress.com/ . My application uses Spring MVC in the backend/server side and AngularJS as a frontend technology.

My question is the following: is there a way to retrieve these latest posts by using Spring or AngularJS ? I've tried the example presented here: http://www.fldtrace.com/display-latest-post-outside-of-wordpress-with-json-and-jquery , replacing the link in the example with my blog link, but it didn't work, as I receive a 404 Not Found error when the application tries to retrieve the posts. I've looked around a bit and some people suggested using the RSS feed that wordpress provides, but I am not sure in which direction I am supposed to be looking, as I am quite new to blogging and linking a blog with an outside application.

Any help is much appreciated. I am not limited to AngularJS, but I would prefer a solution in either Angular, or JavaScript/jQuery/JSON.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have installed [json api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin to your wordpress instance?

Comment: Hm, at the moment no. I am having a bit of difficulties figuring out if I can do this for my blog. I don't have a domain of my own and I am currently hosting it directly on wordpress. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution, based on the code you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/b8Wcz/

Basically, I define a method like the following one in my AngularJS service, and I then invoke it in my AngularJS controller:

**AngularJS**

```
angular.module('blog-module').factory('blogService', function($http) {

return {
    parseFeed : function(){
        return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent('https://thisismyblog.wordpress.com/feed/'));
    }
}

});
```

In your controller, you'll then have something like this:

```
blogService.parseFeed().then(function (feeds) {
        $scope.feeds = feeds.data.responseData.feed.entries;
});
```

This solved my problem.